# evaluating the sum of a geometric series to infinity with n = 10

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to evalute:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=10}^{\infty} u_n$
$a = 240$ and $r = \frac{2}{3}$

from the previous question i have worked out the first term a which is 240 and the ratio r which is 2/3 and the sum to infinity which is 720.

the final answer is get is 707.514 to 3 decimal places.

is this correct ?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what is here to summarize ?

Answer (score 0):

If we have $$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i}$$

Then if we manipulate the sum in the following way: $$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} = ar^{10} + ar^{11} + ar^{12} + \ ...$$
$$r\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} = ar^{11} + ar^{12} + ar^{13} + \ ...$$

$$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} - r\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} = ar^{10}$$
$$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i}\Big(1 - r \Big) = ar^{10}$$
$$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} = \frac{ar^{10}}{1-r} \tag{1}$$

Use $(1)$ and the fact that $ar^{10} = 240$ and $r = \frac{2}{3}$, as you said:

$$\sum_{i = 10}^{\infty}ar^{i} = \frac{240}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{240}{\frac{1}{3}} = 720$$

So $720$ is correct, not $707.514$.